# Multiple bootstrap Modals not closing second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have multiple Modals loaded from separate files through ajax in a div container, first modal opens when user clicks on open button on main page and second modal is opened from a button on the first modal.

The problem is when I click on close button  of the second Modal it closes well on the first time but when I click on it second time It just doesn't respond at all. only if I click on the backdrop several time it closes. My code sample is below.

I am using Jquery 2.1.1 and bootstrap 3.2.0

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="no-js" dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="assets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<title></title>
</head>

<body class="fixed-header">
  <div class="full-height sm-p-t-30 full-height-adjust">
    <a data-target="#selectOptions" data-toggle="modal" href="#" id=
    "loadOptions">Open</a>
 </div>

    <div id="SelectOptionsContainer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function() {
    //loading Modal content into dom  first and then displaying the modal.
    $("#loadOptions").click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'SelectOptions.html',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data) {
                // todo:  add the html to the dom...
                $("#SelectOptionsContainer").html(data);
                $('.modal').modal({
                    show: true
                });
                //loading Modal content into dom  first and then displaying the modal.
                $("#requestCert").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'RequestCertificate.html',
                        dataType: 'text',
                        success: function(
                            data) {
                            // todo:  add the html to the dom...
                            $("#selectOptions").append(data);
                            $('.modal').modal({show: true})
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**Modal 1 selectOptions.html**

```
<div class="modal fade slide-up" id="selectOptions">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content-wrapper">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header clearfix text-left">
                    <button class="close pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" type=
                    "button"><span>&times;</span></button>

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalSlideUpLabel">slide2</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a class="cui-btn-border cui-btn cui-full-width"
                            data-toggle="modal" href="#" id="installCert">Slide
                            1 ( No modal attached)</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a class="cui-btn-border cui-btn cui-full-width"
                            data-target="#requestCertificate" data-toggle=
                            "modal" href="#" id="requestCert">Slide 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Modal 2 RequestCertificate.html**

```
<div class="modal fade slide-up" id="requestCertificate">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content-wrapper">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header clearfix text-left">
                    <button class="close pull-right fa fa-close fs-14"
                    data-dismiss="modal" style="font-style: italic" type=
                    "button"></button>

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalSlideUpLabel">Slide
                    2</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h5>test 2:</h5>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="cui-btn cui-btn-med cui-full-width" id=
                    "btnCancel" type="button">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><script type="text/javascript">

    $('#btnCancel').click(function(){
    $('#requestCertificate').modal('toggle');
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried giving your modal-body elements specific id's?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't worked.